# Jquery UI : How can I update id on drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am making simple drag n drop for just my practice. I am dragging the element and dropping it into the drop zone and there are two div drag me and duplicate me they both are working but in duplicate function I am incrementing the id that is **test-clone-1** it is working fine. I just want to know that how can I increment the id on drop because on drop the default id is **test-clone-1** as it is incrementing on duplicating like ( **test-clone-2**, **test-clone-3** ). I want that if the I drag n drop the element the default id is **test-clone-1** and when I again drag n drop now the id should be **test-clone-2** but the drag n drop and duplicate id increment should be releted to each other

```
$( "#editorDesignView" ).droppable({
        accept: '.textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = '<div id="test-clone-1" class="test" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p><div style="padding:10px; width:50%;" class="draggable-area">drag me</div><div style="padding:10px;width:50%;" class="js-duplicate">duplicate me</div></div>';
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();

      }
    });
  $('#editorDesignView').sortable({
  handle: '.draggable-area'
  });
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/pL4Lv6r9/77/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real way to do it is to count the div elements which have an `id` begining with `test-clone-` in `editorDesignView`.

```
var cloneCount = $("#editorDesignView").find("div[id^='test-clone-']").length+1;
```

`cloneCount` now hold the number to give to the dropped element.

And this is the same for a dragged clone (re-ordering).
This will ensure the right number.

Actually, if you re-ordered the clones, the last element is the reference and may not have the highest number.

So here is your [**updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/vzkwoz4b/).

Comment: one thing I would like to know that if I want id some thing like this ( test-clone-45f63( random number )-1 )

Comment: You can use the `^=` operator for "begin with" and the `*=` for "contains". Now if you use random numbers, you no longer will ensure unique `id`, since random number may repeat... And random-1 may already exist. If you want to randomise one part, it should not be the one which make the `id` unique... And there must be a fixed part if you want to count the elements if you use `the id` to count them. You could use a class for it.

Comment: I think it is useless... since a incremental part is mandatory. ;)

Comment: But if the objective is to "disguise" the id so console sniffers would scratch their head... You could do something like [random 5 numbers][incremental 2 digits from 01 to 99][random part 3 numbers]. And it would be hard to notice the incrementation. And `id` would be unique because of digits at position 6 and 7... haha... ;) And use a class to count the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this? When you drag and drop c gets incremented and when duplicatie the c stays the same?

```
  var c = 1;
  $(".textTemplate").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    zIndex: 2500,
  });
  $( "#editorDesignView" ).droppable({
        accept: '.textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = '<div id="test-clone-'+c+'" class="test" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here. ' + c + '</p><div style="padding:10px; width:50%;" class="draggable-area">drag me</div><div style="padding:10px;width:50%;" class="js-duplicate">duplicate me</div></div>';
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();
        c++;
      }
    });
  $('#editorDesignView').sortable({
  handle: '.draggable-area'
  });
```